# Can not use gtk3 FileChooser on Mac OSX?

Tags: c, macos, gtk, glib

I migrated my program built with gtk+3.0 from linux to Mac OS X(10.6.8).
And I compiled the program without errors.
However, after I started the program and I chose to open a file, the terminal shows following message.

`GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' is not installed`

Then, the program ends with `Segmentation fault`.

How to solve it?
Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger?

Comment: How did you install GTK 3 on Mac?

Comment: @ptomato by mac port, `port install gtk3`

Comment: Sounds like you should install `gsettings-desktop-schemas` (ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gsettings-desktop-schemas/3.2/), not available from MacPorts. If this solves your problem, then report a bug on MacPorts.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you're not the one having this problem, and it [also happens on Windows on MinGW](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-April/msg00094.html). Luckily, that person gave a solution:

> The thing, as it seems as I was running the test-widget example (that I
>   built with gtksourceview-3.0.0 using MSVC), was that I need to compile the
>   org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml file (from GTK+-3.x, under 
>   $(srcroot)/gtk) with the glib-compile-schemas utility that is from GLib, 
>   which will generate gschemas.compiled in the same folder.
>
> After that, place that gschemas.compiled file in the this folder:
>   $(parent_folder_of_the_gtk3_dll)\share\glib-2.0\schemas
>   and one will be set to use the gtkfilechooser without the puzzling
>
> [GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser'
>   is not installed] error.
>
> I will add to my GLib project files to compile the glib-compile-schemas 
>   utility and add to my GTK+-3.x project files to compile the
>   the org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem with a program that I crosscompiled with mingw for windows, the solutions is to run  `glib-compile-schemas [path to org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema]` in my case was that file in ./share/glib-2.0/schemas.It will generate `gschemas.compiled`, that is the file FileChooser is looking for.