# How to fix error "GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system"?

Tags: c++, opencv, gtk3, glib, filechooser

I have to create a one-file (.exe) program with `InstallShield2015LimitedEdition` that works with `GTK3.4.2` and `OpenCV 3.0.0` in `Windows 7 x64`. In this program the user can choose a directory from their computer. But when I invoke FileChooser (click on executable) I get this error:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
```

[image]

and the program terminates.

I visited these pages:

[Glib-GIO-ERROR when opening an file chooser dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370294/glib-gio-error-when-opening-an-file-chooser-dialog)

[GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953925/glib-gio-error-no-gsettings-schemas-are-installed-on-the-system)

[How deal with FileChooser in GTK with static compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257778/how-deal-with-filechooser-in-gtk-with-static-compilation?lq=1)

But I never understood exactly how to fix this error. It is related to `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` file in this path: `...\share\glib-2.0\schemas`.

Is it related to `system environment variable`? What things should I add to it?

[image]

Add to `system variable` or `User variable`? What is `name` and `path`?

For example. I added `GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR` as `variable name` and `E:\Works for Gov Project\Help\Source codes for GTK+\gtk+-bundle_3.4.2-20130513_win64\share\glib-2.0\schemas` as `path` for both of `system variable` and `User variable`.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it:

First: add `GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR` as `variable name` and `E:\Works for Gov Project\Help\Source codes for GTK+\gtk+-bundle_3.4.2-20130513_win64\share\glib-2.0\schemas` as `path` for `User variable`.

Then, in `system variable` ---> `path` add `E:\Works for Gov Project\Help\Source codes for GTK+\gtk+-bundle_3.4.2-20130513_win64\share\glib-2.0\schemas` with `;` in first it, e.g. `;E:\Works for Gov Project\Help\Source codes for GTK+\gtk+-bundle_3.4.2-20130513_win64\share\glib-2.0\schemas`